# UsernameToken with Timestamp token || Python || WS-Security (WSSE)

Tags: python, soap, ws-security, zeep, wsse

I should recreate this part of the payload using python.

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-C85E4BAAC54A3C164416475054038092">
        <wsu:Created>2022-03-17T08:23:23.809Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2022-03-17T08:24:23.809Z</wsu:Expires>
     </wsu:Timestamp>
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-C85E4BAAC54A3C164416475053981971">
        <wsse:Username>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">zL/iJlH2YPm83y+t0wd3Dw==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2022-03-17T08:23:18.195Z</wsu:Created>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

After some research I discovered that there is a library, called "zeep" that deals with this, the only problem is that from what I saw there is very little documentation about it.

**UsernameToken with Timestamp token**

**To use UsernameToken with Timestamp token, first you need an instance of WSU.Timestamp(), then extend it with a list containing WSU.Created() and WSU.Expired() elements, finally pass it as timestamp_token keyword argument to UsernameToken().**

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from zeep import Client
>>> from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
>>> from zeep.wsse.utils import WSU
>>> timestamp_token = WSU.Timestamp()
>>> today_datetime = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> expires_datetime = today_datetime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
>>> timestamp_elements = [
...         WSU.Created(today_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")),
...         WSU.Expires(expires_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
...]
>>> timestamp_token.extend(timestamp_elements)
>>> user_name_token = UsernameToken('username', 'password', timestamp_token=timestamp_token)
>>> client = Client(
...     'http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?WSDL', wsse=user_name_token
...)
```

**Output**

```
<Element {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp at 0x7f46e09032c0>
2022-03-17 09:38:20.627353
2022-03-17 09:48:20.627353
[<Element {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Created at 0x7f46e0903400>, <Element {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Expires at 0x7f46e0916f40>]
None
<zeep.wsse.username.UsernameToken object at 0x7f46e0911fa0>
<zeep.client.Client object at 0x7f46e0911f40>
```

This is all that is said regarding my case, does anyone know how I could build this piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what issue you are facing, but that code should be sufficient to get something working. Maybe the output is not what you expect, so I'll expand a bit on that.

[Assuming this is the WSDL of that service](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LefterisXris/Web-Services-Webpage/master/App_WebReferences/net/webservicex/www/ConvertSpeed.wsdl) (since the webservice itself isn't working), in order to call it and also add the security header, you could do this:

```
import datetime
from zeep import Client
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
from zeep.wsse.utils import WSU
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin
from lxml import etree

def print_history(h):
    print(etree.tostring(h.last_sent["envelope"], encoding = "unicode", pretty_print = True))
    print(etree.tostring(h.last_received["envelope"], encoding = "unicode", pretty_print = True))

timestamp_token = WSU.Timestamp()
today_datetime = datetime.datetime.today()
expires_datetime = today_datetime + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 10)

timestamp_elements = [
    WSU.Created(today_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")),
    WSU.Expires(expires_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
]

timestamp_token.extend(timestamp_elements)
user_name_token = UsernameToken('username', 'password', timestamp_token = timestamp_token)

history = HistoryPlugin()
client = Client(
     'http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?WSDL', 
     wsse = user_name_token,
     plugins = [history]
)

response = client.service.ConvertSpeed(100.00, 'kilometersPerhour', 'milesPerhour')

print_history(history)
```

The call to the service will produce the following SOAP message:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Created>2022-03-20T14:33:15Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2022-03-20T14:43:15Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:ConvertSpeed xmlns:ns0="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <ns0:speed>100.0</ns0:speed>
      <ns0:FromUnit>kilometersPerhour</ns0:FromUnit>
      <ns0:ToUnit>milesPerhour</ns0:ToUnit>
    </ns0:ConvertSpeed>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

If you want to use zeep, I suggest you use it with the real service you are trying to call, not with some sample from the Internet that isn't available. I guess in the zeep documentation they needed some example service to call, but I'm not even sure that service wanted an authentication header.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
How did you figure out how to use this library?
I honestly thought that piece of code wasn't enough to get that result, but from the documentation I couldn't understand much more...

Comment: @mattia.marteddu: I guess I have enough experience with these things to not be bothered by the slim documentation